# Como faço para exibir o nome de uma pessoa na mensagem do onclick="alert()"?

Tags: php, html

Fiz um arquivo de cadastro de clientes eu queria inserir o nome do cliente no `onclick="alert()"` toda vez que a operação de cadastro fosse feita mostrando o nome dele com a mensagem `Cliente fulano cadastrado com sucesso`. Como faço isso?

```
<form method="POST">
<p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
<p> <input type="submit" name="Inserir" onclick="alert('Cliente $nome cadastrado com sucesso')" value="Cadastrar cliente"> </p>
</form>
```

```
// No PHP
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas você gostaria de concatenar o ```Nome``` com o quê? Se puder reformular melhor a sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu gostaria de exibir o nome do cliente na mensagem que é exibida no ```onclick="alert()"```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brothão, acho que fazer isso com JavaScript fique melhor e mais fácil do que fazer com PHP.

Ao clicar no botão chamamos a função exibirNome().

Quando a função exibirNome() é chamada, ela só exibe o alert() se a variável "nome" não tiver vazia.

O document.querySelector() passa o valor que está no campo com id "nome" para a variável "nome".

```js
function exibirNome() {
  let nome = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
  //Esse IF serve para só chamar o alert se o nome for preenchido (a variável nome tiver valor
  if (nome) {
    alert("Cliente " + nome + " cadastrado com sucesso");
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size=30 maxlength="30" required> </p>
  <p> <input type="submit" name="Inserir" onclick="exibirNome()" value="Cadastrar cliente"> </p>
</form>
```

O ideal seria você exibir a mensagem de "Sucesso", somente depois de verificar se realmente a operação foi realizada com sucesso no PHP. Pois, desse jeito que você está fazendo, a mensagem é exibida antes dos dados irem para o PHP e a inserção dos dados realmente ser feita no banco.

Corre o risco de acontecer algum erro e os dados não serem inseridos no banco, sendo que, mesmo assim, a mensagem de "Sucesso" já teria sido exibida.

Se quiser que eu formule a resposta para esse caso, deixe um comentário, então eu edito a resposta e coloco essa opção também.

Veja se serve pra você. Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar. Até mais!

Comment: Tem razão, desse jeito ficou melhor, obrigado.

Comment: De nada, amigão.

Comment: Nesse caso seria melhor colocar mensagem assim: Cliente xxxxx estamos processando seu cadastro :)

Comment: Exacto, Leozinho.